# Print last 5 values from array maintaining order?

Tags: php

Having array:

```
$array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7);
```

how do I print:

```
3,4,5,6,7
```

?

Comment: Was the 3 left out unintentionally?

Comment: '3' isn't in the array. Not sure what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print_r(array_slice($array,-5));
```

[`array_slice` on PHP.net](http://php.net/array-slice)

Answer (score 0):

Use array_slice

```
print_r(array_slice($array, 5))
```

Comment: This outputs "Array", not at all what they're looking for :p

Comment: Good point :L what an oversight. And damn, you beat me by less than a minute (though probably for the best, hehe)